# Is it good to call a model function from a view

Tags: codeigniter

While working on codeigniter, I sorted out one thing that I can call model function from view page also.

For an example

here's my example model

```
<?php
class autoload_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
   }

/*---------data fetching-----------*/
    function get_data_from_table($table,$data,$cond)
    {
        $this->db->select($data);
        $this->db->where($cond);
        $result= $this->db->get($table);
        return $result;
    }
   /*---------ends-----------*/
}
?>
```

Now in my view page i have written this

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Product Title</td>
<td><Product Price</td>
</tr>


<?php
$product_list = $this->autoload_model->get_data_from_table("td_product","*",
                                                           "product_id > 0")->result_array();

if(count($product_list)>0)
    {
      foreach($product_list as $pl)
         {?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $pl['product_title'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pl['product_price'];?></td>
      </tr>
        <?php
         }
     }
    else
     {?>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="2">No data Found</td>
         </tr>
    <?php
     }
}?>
</table>
```

the whole things works fine, its just that I want to know whether its good to use in such fashion or not?

```
NOTE:
```

The autoload model is automaticaly loaded in the config/autoload.php file

Comment: Take a look at this trad

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621725/mvc-model-view-controller-does-the-view-call-the-model

Comment: this is possible but you shouldn't do it
you can put this in the controller and pass the array to the view

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is PHP Framework which built on top of the MVC (Model - View - Controller) design pattern. if you do not follow this then do not use framework

Comment: There are some situation, where its better to call a model function from view...Say i want to have a common section to be shown in all pages, that means in all the controllers i have to put that code section for fetching and displaying the data... if i have 51 controllers, then i may need to add that code to 51 controllers but if i add that in just a common php view file, then all i ned is just to load the view page in each conroller.......... say i want to display a data in header.... then i can directly call the model_function in head section

Comment: nobody stopping you to do that but it is a mvc..if you have a lot of controller means you have a lot of view also..and it's kind of messy

Comment: @Saswat no you do not! in "oop" you can extend controllers, so you make one default controller lets call it "SiteController", now you extend My_Controller with "SiteController" now you write function only once declare it in SiteController and you have this function avalible in every controller that you declare like `...Hello extends SiteController...` please see this tutorial http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY , have fun.

Answer (score 0):

In one word: **NO**.

**Why?**

1) Since codeigniter is a **`MVC Framework`**, we should follow some **`defined protocols`** of MVC.
2) We've to see that how a MVC Framework works and accordingly we've to use it.
3) So how CI works?
   - Firstly, we have a **`URL`** which loads a particular page.
   - The **`routes`** checks the routes matching the URL and calls particular Controller.
   - If no match found in routes, it then checks the matching **`Controller`** and **`Function`**
   - Controller calls the **`model`** with addon data, and models uses that data for **`database operations`**.
   - Models then returns required data back to the Controller and then Controller loads the **`view`** using that data.

**CI Flow:**

> Request **--->** Routing **--->** Controller **--->** Model/Libraries/Helpers/Plugins **--->** Controller **--->** Views

**Your answer:**

1) Calling models in views will work anyways (if model is autoloaded) but still it's **`wrong`**. Doing that means we're **`breaking MVC rules`**.
2) Also you can see in above flow that there is **`no connection`** between models and views.
3) **So where can we call models:** controllers, libraries, helpers.

Answer (score 0):

so another way of looking at this - you are calling the view to render a product table - but you have not confirmed whether there are products.

the **controller calls a product model** and requests products. if products come back then the **controller assigns an appropriate view** for displaying products and passes the products_list object (or array) to the view. there should not be any code in the middle of a table in a view like

```
if(count($product_list)>0)
```

the only php code the view should have is things like

```
foreach($product_list as $pl)
```

to display the products. the value of $product_list comes from the model. so if for example your database table name changes -- that change is done in the model -- not the view.

and if NO products come back from the model - then there is no $product_list. the controller assigns a view where the user can search/browse for other products. we don't need an if(count) in the view because we already know what the search results are.